# if an ideal in the ring of integers contains two relatively prime numbers, then the ideal is equal to ring of integers

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

This is from Ireland and Rosen's A Classical Introduction to Modern number theory.
Let D be the ring of integers in a number field. Let Z be an ideal of D. 
In the proof proposition 13.1.3 it states that if Z contains two relatively prime elements then Z=D.

I don't see how. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $\;a,b,\in I\le\Bbb Z\;$ and

$$gcd(a,b)=1\iff \exists\,x,y\in\Bbb Z\;\;s.t.\;\;ax+by=1\implies 1\in I\implies\ldots$$

Comment: I am not an expert, (still working through this book myself) but does this argument work in the context of prop. 13.1.3 i.e. in any ring of integers of a quadratic number field?

Comment: In page $5$ they define "relatively prime": two elements whose only common divisors are the ring's units. In the question's context, if a principal ideal $\;(p)\;$ has two rel. prime elements, say $\,a,b\;$ ,then $a=pm\;,\;b=pn\iff p\mid a\;\;and\;\;p\mid b\;$ By the mere definition, $\;p\;$ must be a unit and thus $\;(p)=D\;$ . I certainly did *not* notice the OP was talking of a particular case in a particular problem in a particular book (I also I'm re-reading that book!), but as you can see things fit.

Comment: Thank *you*, @OldJohn...and please do not delete your comment: I think it is really helpful.